# How to start a QApplication from shell without blocking it?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qapplication

I have a simple Qt5 Application which can be installed as a pip package.
The package has an entry point so i can start the application via a command prompt.
The called function looks like the following:

```
def start_app():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()

    app.exec()
    sys.exit()
```

And the MainWindow (minimal working example):

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
```

**The problem** is that now the command prompt IS the main application, so if i close the prompt, the python app closes too. Furthermore the command prompt is "blocked", so no additional commands can be entered.

**My goal** is to just use the command prompt to start the app and close it after or use it for other commands. As an example we can take the Spyder app, which can be started via the command `spyder`, which does not block the command prompt. Sadly, I was not able to reverse engineer the spyder code with my current knowledge.

**Edit 1**: For clarification: I do not want any shell to be visible, only the Qt GUI. Also i want to achieve to open the app with a single command (like `spyder`) without any command-line parameters, like you see in the comments.

**Edit 2:** Target OS is Windows.

The package is set up like the following way, so the command to start the app would be `start_app`.

```
setup(
    ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['start_app = package.module:start_app']
    },
    ...
)
```

**I've tried** using QThreads and looked up similar questions but could not get it running, not even close.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What about `start "" "python.exe myscript.py"`?

Comment: @musicamante this does not work because it is an package and i would get relative import errors. Also, my goal is to just use a **single** command.

Comment: What are the target OS? Windows? Or Linux?

Comment: @jlandercy Target os is Windows

Comment: @mitsubishi it doesn't matter if it's a package, just use the proper command or create a proper script and rename it to pyw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `gui_scripts` as an entry point, not `console_scripts`.
Should have read the documentation more carefully: [Entry points specification](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/#use-for-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a bash shell you can use `CTRL+Z` to send a running process to background. Or run your app with a trailing `&` at the end of the command to start the process in background from beginning.

Comment: This does not work! `CTRL+Z` or other key combinations are not accepted until the app exited.

Comment: On Linux `command &` does detach the terminal from the command. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/90464

Comment: I am working on windows, so that explains why it is not working i guess.

Comment: ok, on windows you may try with `start` before the command to start your app. Or consider installing a WSL environment